# Polyhedra has more corners than facets

Tags: polyhedra, discrete-geometry

Let $P$ be a polyhedron. Is it true that $P$ has always more/as many corners than facets? I haven't found a counterexample in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ and intuitively I think the statement is true. Is there a proof?

Comment: Try using $V-E+F=2$?

Comment: Nope. see this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/debnL.png) for an polyhedron with $12$ faces and $9$ vertices.

Comment: Is it also passible if $P$ has to be convex? @achillehui

Comment: Yes, just push the "fan" on top of the polyhedron in previous comment towards the face of pyramid it rest on as much as possible.  Similar construction/procedure for other combination of $f \ge v$ will give you a convex polyhedron.

Comment: “I haven't found a counterexample” is a little bit puzzling, since you have missed both the regular octahedron and the triangular dipyramid (which is just two tetrahedra stuck together).  I would have expected both of those to be among the first ten polyhedra you checked. Can I suggest that you assemble a more comprehensive list of examples? If you have a conjecture about polyhedra, you can check it with the 5 platonic solids, a couple of  prisms and antiprisms, maybe the other five [deltahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltahedron), some things like that.

Answer (score 8):

In $\Bbb R^2$ the claim is trivial, since every polygon always has the same number of sides and vertices.

In $\Bbb R^3$, it's definitely false.  For every polyhedron that has $F$ facets and $C$ corners, there is a so-called “dual” polyhedron that has $C$ facets and $F$ corners.

For example, the cube has 6 facets and 8 corners.  Its dual is the [regular octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron), which has 8 facets but only 6 corners.

[image: regular octahedron]

Did I misunderstand what you meant by "facets" and "corners"?